# If $Z$ is standard normal and $f$ is analytic. Is $g(t)= E[ f(Z-t)]$ analytic?

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, analytic-functions

Let $Z$ be a standard normal.
Now define
\begin{align}
g(t)= E[ f(Z-t)]
\end{align}
where $f(x)$ is a real-analytic function  and $|f(x)| \le x^4$.

**Question:**
Is it true that $g(t)$ is also a real analytic function?

If this is true can we show this without using complex analysis tools?

Comment: @ChristianRemling But Morera is a tool from complex analysis, right?

Comment: If $|f(x)| \leqslant |x|^4$ holds only on the real line, then I doubt the answer to the question is indeed "yes". At least, Morera's theorem cannot be applied directly: consider, for example, $f(x) = \exp(i \exp(x^2))$, which is bounded on the real line, but behaves badly in any strip $\{|\operatorname{Im} x| < \varepsilon\}$.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki: Yes, this is a good point, we will need control on $f$ on a strip or at least an open set containing $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

$E(f(Z-t)) = \int f(x) e^{-\frac {x^2} 2} e^{tx - \frac {t^2} 2} dx =e^{ \frac {t^2} 2} \int f(x) e^{-\frac {x^2} 2} e^{tx} dx  $.  $$$$  $e^{ \frac {t^2} 2}$ is an analytic function of t, and the integral pretty clearly is too, even complex analytic even if f is only real analytic.  This clearly has not much to do with f, only that it is not too large.

Comment: You can not choose you $f$ to be like this.  First, you have to specify $f(x)$ and then you plug it into the expectation by setting $x=Z-t$.   You can not do this with the function you picked.

Comment: This argument seems fine to me (modulo a missing factor of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ and a sign error).  The expectation ${\bf E} f(Z-t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int f(x-t) e^{-x^2/2}\ dx$ can be rewritten as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int f(x) e^{-(x+t)^2/2}\ dx$ after a change of variables $x \mapsto x+t$.  One now has complex analyticity from Morera's theorem; one could also proceed in a real variable fashion by Taylor expansion and Fubini.